# Creating HTML form for survey

Tags: html

I'm fairly new to html but agreed to help out a friend (who is even more new to it) with a project - creating a survey to collect some data. I have done what I can but there are a couple of kinks I still haven't worked out. As this project needs to be sped up a little, I don't have the luxury of waiting until I've learned more and must ask for help.

Here's the part I'm having problems with (the content of the survey has been removed as the information is not mine to give):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>Survey form</h1>

    <form action="action_page.php" method="post">

    <p>Yes or no question 1</p>
      <input type="radio" name="Success" value="Yes" checked> Yes
      <input type="radio" name="Success" value="No"> No

    <p>PLease provide details of each individual.</p>
     <table id="t01">
    <tr>
     <th>Id #</th>
     <th>Year</th>
     <th>Detail 2</th> 
     <th>Detail 3</th>
     <th>County</th>
     <th>Detail 5</th> 
     <th>Detail 6</th>
     <th>Detail 7</th>
     <th>Detail 8</th> 
     <th>Detail 9</th>
     <th>Detail 10</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
     <input list="Year", name="Year">
      <datalist id="Year">
        <option value="2015">
        <option value="2014">
        <option value="2013">
        <option value="2012">
        <option value="2011">
        <option value="2010">
        <option value="2009">
        <option value="2008">
        <option value="2007">
        <option value="2006">
        <option value="2005">
        <option value="2004">
        <option value="2003">
        <option value="2002">
        <option value="2001">
        <option value="2000">
        <option value="1999">
        <option value="1998">
        <option value="1997">
        <option value="1996">
        <option value="1995">
        <option value="1994">
        <option value="1993">
        <option value="1992">
        <option value="1991">
        <option value="1990">
        <option value="Before 1990">
      </datalist>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input list="Detail 2", name="Detail 2">
      <datalist id="Detail 2">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
        <option value="3">
        <option value="4">
        <option value="5">
      </datalist>
    </td> 
    <td>
      <input list="Detail 3", name="Detail 3">
      <datalist id= "Detail">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
        <option value="3">
      </datalist>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input list="County", name="County">
      <datalist id="County">
        <option value="Antrim">
        <option value="Armagh">
        <option value="Carlow">
        <option value="Cavan">
        <option value="Clare">
        <option value="Cork">    
        <option value="Derry">
        <option value="Donegal">
        <option value="Down">
        <option value="Dublin">
        <option value="Fermanagh">
        <option value="Galway">  
        <option value="Kerry">
        <option value="Kildare">
        <option value="Kilkenny">
        <option value="Loais">
        <option value="Leitrim">
        <option value="Limerick">    
        <option value="Longford">
        <option value="Lough">
        <option value="Mayo">
        <option value="Meath">
        <option value="Monaghan">
        <option value="Offaly">    
        <option value="Roscommon">
        <option value="Sligo">
        <option value="Tipperary (North)">
        <option value="Tipperary (South)">  
        <option value="Tyrone">
        <option value="Waterford">
        <option value="Westmeath">
        <option value="Wexford">
        <option value="Wiclow">
      </datalist>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input list="Detail 5", name="Detail 5">
      <datalist id="Detail 5">
        <option value="Yes">
        <option value="No">
      </datalist>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input list="Detail 6", name="Detail 6">
      <datalist id="Detail 6">
        <option value="Yes">
        <option value="No">
      </datalist>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input list="Detail 7", name="Detail 7">
      <datalist id="Detail 7">
        <option value="Yes">
        <option value="No">
      </datalist>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input list="Detail 8", name="Detail 8">
      <datalist id="Detail 8">
        <option value="Yes">
        <option value="No">
      </datalist>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input list="Year", name="Year">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input list="Detail 9", name="Detail 9">
      <datalist id="Detail 9">
        <option value="1">
        <option value="2">
        <option value="3">
        <option value="4">
        <option value="5">
        <option value="6">
        <option value="7">
        <option value="8">
        <option value="9">
        <option value="10">
        <option value="11">
        <option value="12">
        <option value="13">
        <option value="14">
        <option value="15">
        <option value="16">     
        <option value="Other (Please specify)">
      </datalist>
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea name="message" rows="1" cols="30">
        Please detail other here:
      </textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
    
    <button onclick="addRowFunction()">Add Row</button>

    <script>
    function addRowFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("t01");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
    var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
    var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);
    var cell12 = row.insertCell(11);
    
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell5.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell6.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell7.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell8.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell9.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell10.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell11.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell12.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";    
    }
    </script>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>     

    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see, it's a great, ugly thing but, style aside, it's pretty much doing what I want. The only exceptions are:

1. My function to add rows to my table - Ideally I would like this to add rows to the bottom of the table (rather than the top) that duplicate the content of the row above (options to each detail - not simply "new cell") but adds 1 to the Id# of each row. I have tried doing this a couple of ways but haven't yet cracked it.
2. Submitting the data - here I'm really out of my depth. I have only the vaguest idea of how to make the data go somewhere and, at present, amn't even sure it has somewhere to go. I know it's in the line  but setting up an "action_page.php" is a mystery, as is the format in which the data are actually stored. Any advice on a simple way to do this, or a link to somewhere with said advice, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading. If I can make the problem any easier to understand please let me know.

Comment: Do you want to send the data directly to an email address?

Comment: Yes, that is the plan. :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, you can insert at the end of a table using this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
```

Please confirm if you would like the data sent by email in PHP and I will add a sample later.

-- EDIT --

Please take a look at this page to send an email using PHP: [PHP Mail function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Also, you will need to read your form data to build your mail message.  To help you do it, take a look at this page: [PHP Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I would like to send the data to an email address but like I said, complete noob at this. A sample would be great!

Comment: Added the second part of the answer. Sorry if I didn't write all the code for you (time constraint), but the links should guide you well enough.